# Tuning keyboard (dead key) functionality in X

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

My preferred keyboard configuration is US-International. When I use it on MS-Windows and type certain special characters (i.e., `~` `'` `"`) followed by `a`, `o` `n` I get `á` `ó` or `ñ` as I wish.

However when I type these characters followed by a letter that doesn't match, I will get that special character followed by the letter. So if I want to type, let's say, `"q` I can do it by pressing <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. However, if I do the same on Gnome I need to do it like <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>␣</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, otherwise I get an audible bell.

Also, if I want to type two single quotes, in Gnome I need to type <kbd>'</kbd> four times, instead of the two times it takes on MS-windows. I know it is a rather minor annoyance, but it does get to me, and I see GNU+Linux as a highly customizable OS, and I'd like to learn more about how do I do such things. Changing to the normal US keyboard is not an option, because I need to use characters such as `á` `ó` or `ñ` for typing in Spanish.

---

note: I am using Debian

Comment: Well, changing to normal US + compose key is an option, then you'd type compose, ', a for á, compose ', o for ó, compose, ~, n for ñ, etc. But that's more a workaround than a answer to your question of how you modify a keyboard loyout.

Comment: I have the same issue here on KDE. The proposed solutions are all insufficient as they involve more keypresses than I'd like.

Comment: I think, I recently posed the same question just for Linux Mint instead of Debian. See here for my (almost complete) solution using xim: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220510/insert-both-characters-if-a-dead-key-combination-is-not-recognized-e-g-a-%E2%86%92-%C3%A1/223700#223700

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The dead key sequences are configured in the same place as the compose key sequences, in the compose map. The [compose map file](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.html) is loaded by each application when it starts up; the following files are tried in order:

1. the file name indicated by the environment variable `XCOMPOSEFILE`
2. `~/.XCompose`
3. `/usr/share/X11/locale/LOCALE_NAME/Compose` (e.g. `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`)

There's no include mechanism, so if you want to modify the table, you'll need to make a copy of the standard file and edit it.

For example, to define <kbd>dead ¨</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> to insert `"q` and <kbd>dead '</kbd> <kbd>dead '</kbd> to insert `''`:

```
<dead_diaeresis> <q> : "\"q"
<dead_acute> <dead_acute> : "''"
```

You'll have to repeat the `"q` sequence for all letters, there's no macro facility. As far as I know, there's no fallback facility either: if a sequence is defined for `<dead_diaeresis> <a>` but none for `<dead_diaeresis> <q>` then typing `<dead_diaeresis> <q>` will not insert anything.

If you want more sophisticated capabilities, you'll have to move on from the basic compose facility into the world of [input methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method). Input methods are primarily intended for people who use non-alphabetic scripts or multiple scripts, but of course you can use it for diacritics as well. Several input method frameworks are available. Since [Gnome 3.6](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/i18n-ibus.html.en), Gnome integrates support for [iBus](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few US International keyboard layout options, five or so I believe.

You seem to have chosen one with dead keys enabled, try another one. There are some that use Alt Gr combinations e.g. <kbd>alt gr</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> for `ö`.

There is also the option to use the compose key.

<kbd>compose</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> for `ö` (this is what I use), of Alt non-combining then <kbd>alt gr</kbd>o may produce ö or ó or . Experiment with the various settings for keyboard layout.

Another option is to have two layouts, Spanish and US English. You can set a key for switching, and display the current layout in the tray.