# Dvorak layout, but QWERTY with Ctrl or Alt modifiers

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I comfortably type using a keyboard layout named [Light Developer's Dvorak](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512065149/http://www.andong.co.uk/dvorak/DDvorak.aspx?page=Light+DDvorak), which I have further customized (negligibly) for myself.

How do I configure, so that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc. will read the layout as qwerty?, thus keeping keyboard commands. On Windows I do this using AutoHotkey.

Comment: You asked two separate questions, one about dead keys and one about modifier handling. I removed the part about dead keys because it's a duplicate of a question that's already answered on this site: [Tuning keyboard (dead key) functionality in X](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149993/tuning-keyboard-dead-key-functionality-in-x). I can't find a duplicate for the part about modifier handling.

Comment: If you are using KDE, you should have a look at this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214273/101324 If not, please give us further information.