# Where are the definitions for dead key combinations?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, source, dead-keys

I noticed that on Ubuntu 20.04, some dead key combinations act differently than expected. For instance, dead acute followed by `c` produces `ç`, not `ć` as one might expect.

I have found the keyboard layout definitions at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/ (and submitted some merge requests for unrelated changes), but could not find any definitions for dead key combinations in that repo.

These combinations appear to be global (i.e. not bound to a specific layout), as the dead acute behaves the same way on different layouts, e.g. `de(deadtilde)` and `lt(us)`.

Where are the definitions for the dead key mappings on the system? Where is the upstream source repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tuning keyboard (dead key) functionality in X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149993/tuning-keyboard-dead-key-functionality-in-x)

Comment: Thanks, this answers the first part (where is it located on my system). What is still missing is a pointer to upstream.

Comment: Almost there: gitlab.freedesktop.org has `xorg` and `util` underneath, but no `compose-tables` underneath...

Comment: Also, I see that on Ubuntu 20.04, the package seems to be `libx11-data`. As far as I can tell, upstream seems to be at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11, and the compose map for `iso8859-1` is at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/master/nls/iso8859-1/Compose.pre. Note that not every locale seems to be present in the repo.

Comment: @user149408 Was there any advancement in your quest since then ?